# Problem with table output

Tags: tables, tabularx

I have created a simple 3-column table, in which the first row has 3 columns, and in the second row the columns are merged into one. Or at least I wanted to. Unfortunately, the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
  \begin{center}
  \rowcolors{2}{black!0}{black!10}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|r|r|r|}
    \hline
    \cellcolor{black!25}Techniques & Artifacts & Budget \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{Country List} \\ 
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
  \end{center}
\end{document}
```

returns the following output :sigh:

[image]

Yeah, I need some shading, as depicted, so, sorry about the extra code.

Comment: `tabularx` requires at least one `X`  column. Replace `{ccc}` in the tabularx preamble with `{*3{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}}`.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the new package `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={*3{X[r]}},
        row{even} = {black!10},
        cell{1}{1} = {black!25},
        hlines,
        vlines
        }
    Techniques & Artifacts & Budget \\
    \SetCell[c=3]{l}Country List & &\\
    A & B & 100 \\
    C & D & 200 \\
    \end{tblr}
  \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Compare with the classical method as proposed by Bernard in his comment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
  \begin{center}
  \rowcolors{2}{black!0}{black!10}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*3{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X|}}
    \hline
    \cellcolor{black!25}Techniques & Artifacts & Budget \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{Country List} \\ 
    \hline
    A & B & 100 \\
    \hline
    C & D & 200 \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
  \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the results are similar but the new method has a better vertical spacing.

Comment: Nice answer (+1). However, I would add `\hlines` to table preamble and drop `\hline`s in table body. Also all rows should have all ampersands regardless if in it is multi column cell, so it should be `\SetCell[c=3]{l}Country List & & \\ `.

Comment: @Zarko Done, thanks!